# How can I change this navigation drawer icon to a back arrow that will make an activity return to another activity

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I need to change this drawer icon to a back arrow that will change a Details Activity to a List Activity.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVw4G.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PheSY.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_arrow_icon);
```

and I suggest you read this

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle)

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);      
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, toolbar, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.myicon);//your preferred drawable image here

toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
});
```